# Existence of a value for specific column in table

Tags: sql

I have two tables `Driver` and `Application`.

In `Driver` table for a particular `parttype` and `Weightage` greater than 100 and less than 600, there is an attribute `name` and value in table `application` those values should not be NULL or blank in application table.

If it is blank or NULL then that record should be in output

```
DECLARE @DRIVER TABLE
(
PartType VARCHAR (50),
AttributeName VARCHAR (50),
Weightage VARCHAR (50)
)


INSERT @DRIVER


SELECT 'Air Filter',    'Shape',    '100' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fender Flare',  'Color Group',  '500' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tonneau Cover', 'Lead Type',    '999' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lug Bolt',  'Thread Size',  '100' 



DECLARE @application TABLE
(
Part_Number VARCHAR (50),   
Part_Type  VARCHAR (50),    
Description_1  VARCHAR (50) ,
Description_1_Value  VARCHAR (50),
Description_2    VARCHAR (50),
Description_2_Value  VARCHAR (50),
Description_3    VARCHAR (50),
Description_3_Value  VARCHAR (50)

)

Insert @application


SELECT 'AAA19-1405',    'Air Filter',   'Shape',    'Universal',    'Number 
Of Pieces', '2',    'Design',   'No Logo' Union All
SELECT 'ZORLYM12',  'Air Filter',   'Shape',    '',             'Number Of     
Pieces',    '4',    'Design',   'No Logo' Union All
SELECT 'AAA19-1508',    'Fender Flare', 'Type', 'Universal',    'Color 
Group', 'Red',  'Design',   'No Logo' Union All
SELECT 'NORFLEX89', 'Fender Flare', 'Type', 'Universal',    'Color Group',  
NULL,   'Design',   'No Logo' Union All
SELECT 'AAA19-2305',    'Lug Bolt', 'Type', 'Universal',    'Number Of 
Pieces',    '4',    'Thread Size',  'MAX' UNION ALL
SELECT 'BIOCONINSULIN', 'Lug Bolt', 'Type', 'Universal',    'Number Of 
Pieces',    '4',    'Thread Size',  NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BBB19-2305',    'Tonneau Cover','Lead Type',    NULL,   'Number Of 
Pieces',    '4',    'Thread Size',  NULL union all
SELECT 'XXXXXX',  'Air Filter',   'Shape',    'CATCH',             'Number  
Of Pieces',    '4',    'Design',   NULL Union All
```

Expected output

```
/*
AAA19-1405  Air Filter  Shape   Universal   Number Of Pieces    2   Design  No Logo-- here for part Type Air filter value not present for Shape
NORFLEX89   Fender Flare    Type    Universal   Color Group NULL    Design  No Logo-- COLOR GROUP IS NULL FOR Fender Flare
BIOCONINSULIN   Lug Bolt    Type    Universal   Number Of Pieces    4   Thread Size NULL-- Thread size is Null for part type Lug Bolt
*/
```

-- this should not appear in the output because `Weightage` is greater than 600

```
BBB19-2305  Tonneau Cover   Lead Type   NULL    Number Of Pieces    4   Thread Size NULL
```

Thank you very much

Code i tried but not giving result

```
SELECT * FROM @DRIVER D
INNER JOIN
@application A
ON A.Part_Type = D.PartType
WHERE D.AttributeName in 
(
SELECT Description_1 , Description_2 , Description_3 FROM @APPLICATION

)

AND A.Description_1_Value IS NULL or A.Description_2_Value is null or     
A.A.Description_3_Value IS NULL
```

Comment: Well, **show us your current efforts!** What does your query look like? Where are you stuck??

Comment: @marc_s: i have tried with code but getting error. code included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @DRIVER D
INNER JOIN @application A ON A.Part_Type = D.PartType
WHERE 
    (D.AttributeName = a.Description_1 AND A.Description_1_Value IS NULL)
    OR
    (D.AttributeName = a.Description_2 AND A.Description_2_Value IS NULL)
    OR
    (D.AttributeName = a.Description_3 AND A.Description_3_Value IS NULL)
    AND d.Weightage BETWEEN 100 AND 600
```

**Update:**

The output I'm getting with this `SELECT` statement of mine and the sample data provided by the OP is:

[image]

and I **DO NOT** see any rows with an "Air filter" that are not supposed to show up according to your comments.... please explain in more detail!

Comment: The record where part_number XXXXXX should not appear in the output
because parttype Air filter attribute name shape is neither Null Or Blank.
may anyone please help me to correct the logic

Comment: may any one please help me on this

Comment: @RajeeKasthuri: according to my testing, that row does **NOT** appear with my select statement - I truly **DO NOT** understand what you're trying to accomplish here......

Comment: i am sorry marc, but the present solution is checking for all the description_value which is NULL but what i am trying to check if description_value for description which is equal to the attribute_name is NULL or not.

Comment: for eg: this record (SELECT 'XXXXXX',  'Air Filter',   'Shape',    'CATCH',             'Number  
Of Pieces',    '4',    'Design',   NULL ), should not appear in the output, beacause shape is the attribute for air filter which we want to check

Comment: @RajeeKasthuri: that row does **NOT** appear in my output! As it should ..... what are you talking about??

Comment: i have edited with 1 more row Part_Number as 'XXXXXX'.

Comment: @RajeeKasthuri: ok, updated my response by changing the way the `WHERE` clause is composed. BTW: this having `Description_1`, `Description_2` etc. is a **horribly bad** database design - you should storngly consider changing this to a **proper, relational** design instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98885/discussion-between-rajee-kasthuri-and-marc-s).